# Creating a series of 2-dimensional arrays from a text file in Julia

Tags: arrays, file-io, julia

I'm trying to write a Sudoku solver, which is the fun part. The un-fun part is actually loading the puzzles into Julia from a text file. The text file consists of a series of puzzles comprising a label line followed by 9 lines of digits (0s being used to denote blank squares). The following is a simple example of the sort of text file I am using (sudokus.txt):

```
Easy 7
000009001
008405670
940000032
034061800
070050020
002940360
890000056
061502700
400700000
Medium 95
000300100
800016070
000009634
001070000
760000015
000020300
592400000
030860002
007002000
Hard 143
000003700
305061000
000200004
067002100
400000003
003900580
200008000
000490308
008100000
```

What I want to do is strip out the label lines and store the 9x9 grids in an array. File input operations are not my specialist subject, and I've tried various methods such as `read()`, `readcsv()`, `readlines()` and `readline()`. I don't know whether there is any advantage to storing the digits as characters rather than integers, but leading zeros have to be maintained (a problem I have encountered with some input methods and with abortive attempts to use `parse()`).

I've come up with a solution, but I suspect it's far from optimal:

```
function main()
    open("Text Files\\sudokus.txt") do file
        grids = Vector{Matrix{Int}}()
        grid = Matrix{Int}(0,9)
        row_no = 0
        for line in eachline(file)
            if !(all(i -> isnumber(i), line))
                continue
            else
                row_no += 1
                squares = split(line, "")
                row = transpose([parse(Int, square) for square in squares])
                grid = vcat(grid, row)
                if row_no == 9
                    push!(grids, grid)
                    grid = Matrix{Int}(0,9)
                    row_no = 0
                end
            end
        end
        return grids
    end
end

@time main()
```

I initially ran into `@code_warntype` problems from the closure, but I seem to have solved those by moving my `grids`, `grid` and `row_no` variables from the `main()` function to the `open` block.

Can anyone come up with a more efficient way to achieve my objective or improve my code? Is it possible, for example, to load 10 lines at a time from the text file? I am using Julia 0.6, but solutions using 0.7 or 1.0 will also be useful going forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your file is well-structured, by that I mean each 1,11,21... contains difficulty information and the lines between them contains the sudoku rows. Therefore if we know the number of lines then we know the number of sudokus in the file. The code utilizes this information to pre-allocate an array of exactly the size needed.

If your file is too-big then you can play with `eachline` instead of `readlines`. `readlines` read all the lines of the file into the RAM while `eachline` creates an iterable to read lines one-by-one.

```
function readsudoku(file_name)
    lines = readlines(file_name)

    sudokus = Array{Int}(undef, 9, 9, div(length(lines),10)) # the last dimension is for each sudoku

    for i in 1:length(lines)
        if i % 10 != 1  # if i % 10 == 1 you have difficulty line
            sudokus[(i - 1) % 10, : , div(i-1, 10) + 1] .= parse.(Int, collect(lines[i])) # collect is used to create an array of `Char`s
        end
    end

    return sudokus
end
```

This should run on 1.0 and 0.7 but I do not know if it runs on 0.6. Probably, you should remove `undef` argument in `Array` allocation to make it run on 0.6.

Comment: That works nicely, it's neater and quicker than my method and uses less resources. You're right, I needed to remove the `undef` in the `Array` allocation. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Hckr's (faster) approach, my first idea is:

```
s = readlines("sudoku.txt")
smat = reshape(s, 10,3)
sudokus = Dict{String, Matrix{Int}}()
for k in 1:3
    sudokus[smat[1,k]] = parse.(Int, permutedims(hcat(collect.(Char, smat[2:end, k])...), (2,1)))
end
```

which produces

```
julia> sudokus
Dict{String,Array{Int64,2}} with 3 entries:
  "Hard 143"  => [0 0 … 0 0; 3 0 … 0 0; … ; 0 0 … 0 8; 0 0 … 0 0]
  "Medium 95" => [0 0 … 0 0; 8 0 … 7 0; … ; 0 3 … 0 2; 0 0 … 0 0]
  "Easy 7"    => [0 0 … 0 1; 0 0 … 7 0; … ; 0 6 … 0 0; 4 0 … 0 0]
```

Comment: Again, this is a neater solution than mine, quicker and also using less resources. As you say, it's not quite as quick as Hckr's solution and I don't need the labels for my current problem, but I can see that the dictionary-based approach could be useful in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it's not as quick as my method (especially when I load a file of 50 grids), I wasn't comparing like with like (different text files). However, it does use less resources and you've certainly given me food for thought.